# RTCPeerConnection fails when peers on different networks

Tags: typescript, webrtc, stun

I have a prototype web application that uses WebRTC Javascript APIs for (one-way) real-time video streaming (using the RTCPeerConnection API), designed to be streaming from a desktop web app to an iOS hybrid app.

In it's current state, the application successfully streams video when both devices are on the same WiFi connection. However, when I turn off WiFi for the iOS peer, and use a mobile data/4G connection, and then try to re-negotiate the RTCPeerConnection, the RTCPeerConnection ends in a failed state.

I'm supplying Google's public STUN servers to the RTCPeerConnection instance.

```js
        const config: RTCConfiguration = {
            'iceServers': [
                {
                    'urls': [
                        'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302',
                        'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302',
                        'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302',
                        'stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302',
                        'stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302',
                    ]
                },
            ]
        }
        let peer = new RTCPeerConnection(config)
```

I'm not sure what other code that would be helpful to assist debugging this. Again, it works as expected when the peers are on the same WiFi network. If I take the second peer (iOS device) off WiFi and use mobile data, it stops working and RTCPeerConnection eventually has ICE connection state `failed`. I haven't been able to test what happens if the devices are both on WiFi, but on different WiFi networks.

If anyone has advice about debugging, I'd appreciate that too. I attached some event handlers to attempt debugging.

```js
        peer.oniceconnectionstatechange = (ev: Event) => {
            console.log('RTCPeerConnection ICE state change', peer.iceConnectionState, JSON.stringify(ev))
        }

        peer.onicecandidateerror = (ev: RTCPeerConnectionIceErrorEvent) => {
            console.log('ice candidate error', JSON.stringify(ev))
        }
```

From the first one, I get this log line:

```
RTCPeerConnection ICE state change disconnected {"isTrusted":true}
```

However, the latter one, the on error handler, is never called.

Answer (score 0):

1/ STUN servers do not guarantee a connection can be established. TURN servers are required for a higher success rate.

2/ onicecandidate error only deals with errors related to gathering a local candidate, not failure to establish a connection to a peer so that is expected.